# nodejs express detects google chrome's addressbar autocompleter while typing

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

I'm working on a serverside program using nodejs and express, it works as intended but, when I was typing(not even 2 characters of domain), server caught google chromes request(and sent response in return).

**How can I stop my server program responding to google chromes requests while typing an address even at the beginning letter**(it completes but doesn't enter, I hit enter always) but not when it is an actual request by user.

Does google chrome do this even for non-visited sites?

Is there a special request parameter to filter for this so I can pick only real client requests instead of browsers internal(but inbound to my server) requests?

While I'm writing something to addressbar such as "how can i ", it autocompletes with an (already visited) "query a collection"(probably requests from that site) and just over bottom there is (not visited) "love". Does google chrome do a http request to a non-visited-ever love suggestion site?

Google chrome ver: 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)

**Maybe this is a normal behavior for browsers with some prefetch technology?**

Comment: Hmm, why would you want to prevent this from happening? What result is undesirable? A big note to make is that GET request should be mostly idempotent (other than things like analytics). That means, nothing on your server should be mutated for GETs. Google doesn't do this for POSTs btw.

Comment: How to know if user opened+closed page, or, he/she didn't even enter page, just scrolling in addressbar. (such as saving session timings but with tighter timeouts)

Comment: I'd ask that question instead. For instance, you could use "sendBeacon" in JS within an onunload event to get that same information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called as **prerendering** which loads a web page in the background before you finish typing the URL to speed up the page load performance.

It appears that this is undetectable in server side.

An issue was opened for this for the Chromium project.  It's marked as "**won't fix**" ([Prerendering does not have any distinguishing HTTP headers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86175)).  The prefetch request doesn't show up in the Dev Tools "Network" tab, so you can't easily confirm this by look at the headers. When checked them using Wireshark, unfortunately there was no difference distinguishing pre-render requests from "normal" requests.

You can turn off this manually as below but unfortunately you can't differentiate with actual request in server side.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click Menu and then Settings.
3. At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.
4. In the "Privacy" section, uncheck the box next to "Use a prediction
   service to load pages more quickly."

SO Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35091410/7055233

Comment: According to the thread, the only solution is to implement the Page Visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: This pre-rendering request was visible for my rails application and annoyed me for a few days whenever I first opened my application. I was getting two requests for same resource, at similar time. Not only this, sometimes I got concurrency error "ActionView::Template::Error (can't add a new key into hash during iteration)".